# Setting breakpoint at a particular line in a module using gdb

Tags: c++, gdb

So, I have compiled multiple modules together and now I am trying to debug them. However when I use `filename:line_no` , gdb is showing the following error:

```
No source file named PredMin.cpp.
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: How did you compile it? Did you compile with debug information?

Comment: @ThomasSablik, I used 'g++ -std=c++14 .\BST.h '.\Search&Insert.cpp' .\main.cpp .\PredMin.cpp'

Comment: Try it with `g++ -std=c++14 -g .\BST.h '.\Search&Insert.cpp' .\main.cpp .\PredMin.cpp`. That means add the flag `-g` to add symbol information.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Thanks, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile your project with

```
g++ -std=c++14 -g .\BST.h '.\Search&Insert.cpp' .\main.cpp .\PredMin.cpp
```

That means add the flag `-g` to add symbol information.

Answer (score -1):

because you should set the full path .

like gdb> break /Full/path/to/PredMin.cpp:lineno